# How to display all values of uint32 array in variable browser?

Tags: matlab, struct, uint32, uint

I have a struct as shown below:

[image]

I have a problem with this struct. In some fields, instead of the values as in the other fields, it's written `48x1 uint32`. I want to have to numbers as in the other fields, for example `[23;45;67]`.

My problem is that I want to save the struct in a csv file, for then open it with python, and saving the struct as it is in the fields I need the values, instead of `48x1 uint32`.

Comment: Just as with other number-crunching programs (for instance Excel), MATLAB questions are on-topic for StackOverflow only if they involve programming.  Just general point-and-click usage of the software would be on-topic at SuperUser.

Comment: Have a look at my edit also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not relevant if the data type is `double` or `uint32`, just the number of element matters. The maximum number of elements displayed in the variable browser is **10**.

```
a.b = uint32(randi(20,10,1));   %// gets displayed
a.c = double(randi(20,10,1));   %// gets displayed
a.d = uint32(randi(20,11,1));   %// does not get displayed
a.c = double(randi(20,11,1));   %// does not get displayed
```

[image]

I'm not aware of any possibility to change this behavior.

---

> My problem is that I want to save the struct in a csv file, for then
>   open it with python, and saving the struct as it is in the fields I
>   need the values, instead of `48x1 uint32`.

The values are there, there is no difference in-between the rows. But if there are are less than 11 elements in an array you get *a preview of the field content* in the variable browser. But if you type `patients(56)` an `patients(57)` there is no difference in format.